# How to change one columns values based another column via the index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has two columns:

```
A    B

0    0
0    1
0    0
0    0 
0    0
0    1
```

I want to have some code that checks the B column and when a 1 is found, the values of column A from that INDEX on changes to 1 like this;

```
A    B
0    0
1    1
1    0
1    0
1    0
1    1
```

My code is like this but it is not what I want:

```
df['A']= np.where(df['B'] == 1,df['A'], '1')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
df.loc[df['B'].idxmax():, 'A'] = 1
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   A  B
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  1  0
3  1  0
4  1  0
5  1  1
```

If you want to use np.where, do:

```
df['A'] = np.where(df.index < df['B'].idxmax(), df['A'], 1)
print(df)
```

If the column `B` can have other values besides 0s and 1s, do:

```
df['A'] = np.where(df.index < df['B'].eq(1).idxmax(), df['A'], 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `cummax`

```
df['A']=df.B.cummax()
df
Out[302]: 
   A  B
0  0  0
1  1  1
2  1  0
3  1  0
4  1  0
5  1  1
```